# Comparing the trend of several graphs with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can we have multiple plots with different x and y axis scale in one plot?
For example we have the lists a=[0, 1, 2, 3], b=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], c=[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000], aa=[5, 6, 7, 8], bb=[50, 60, 70, 80, 90] and cc=[5000, 6000, 7000, 8000] and we want to have scatter plots of (a, aa), (b, bb), (c, cc) in a plot. When we use plt.scatter(a,aa), plt.scatter(b,bb) and plt.scatter(c,cc), the scale of last plot is applied to all plots. How can we prevent this?

```
for i in range(30):
    plt.scatter(dif_f[i], f_network_data_f[i],  
                label=f'demand{(i*5)+5}')
plt.axhline(0, ls='--', lw= 1, color='blue')
plt.axvline(0, ls='--', lw= 1, color='blue')
plt.xlabel("$ζ_i$ (positive values)")
plt.ylabel("$W_{14,i}$")
plt.title("$W_{14,i}$ versus $ζ_i$"+f" (average of cars per hour from each origin-destinatio)", fontsize=9)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?? Hoping to have understood well...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
aa = [5, 6, 7, 8]
bb = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
cc = [5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
######################################## First scatter plot (a,aa)
ax1.scatter(a, aa, color='blue')
ax1.set_xlabel('scatter plot')
ax1.set_ylabel('a and aa', color='blue')

ax2 = ax1.twinx() # define a second set of axes that shares the same x-axis
######################################## Second scatter plot (b,bb)
ax2.scatter(b, bb, color='red')
ax2.set_ylabel('b and bb', color='red')

ax3 = ax1.twiny() # define a third set of axes that shares the same x-axis
######################################## Third scatter plot (c,cc)
ax3.scatter(c, cc, color='green')
ax3.set_xlabel('c and cc', color='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: for red and green one it's what I want but blue one not. I'm seeking a way that works like twinx and twiny but not only for two plots but also for more than two plots.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot comprehend what you mean by "more than two plots". Assuming that you have 2 new lists 'd' and 'dd', you can continue to add new scatter plots in the same figure, in the same way by adding "ax4 = ax1.twinx()" and "ax4.scatter(d, dd, color='violet')" .

Comment: I just want  to compare trends of multiple plots without paying attention to their scales. imagine you plot lists 'a' and 'aa' then 'b' and 'bb' and etc but when you plot multiple plots in one, the scale of last plot is applied to all data and the visuality of plot is destroyed. I just want to prevent this.